# JS onscroll/scrollTop not working in IE and Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to place floating  code into Joomla Site using javascript.

The code works perfect on Chrome with this script:

```
<script>
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction();};
var towerRightAd = document.getElementById("bodyTowerRightAd");

function myFunction() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 150) {
        if (towerRightAd.className != "bodyTowerRighttAd floatTowerAds" )  {
            towerRightAd.className = towerRightAd.className + " floatTowerAds";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        towerRightAd.className = "bodyTowerRightAd";
    }
}
</script>
```

How can i get this code to work for FF and IE.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/vebenikoje/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
   window.onscroll = function() {
      myFunction();
    };

    var towerRightAd = document.getElementById("bodyTowerRightAd");

    function myFunction() {
      var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

      if (scrollTop > 150) {
        if (towerRightAd.className != "bodyTowerRighttAd floatTowerAds" ) {
           towerRightAd.className = towerRightAd.className + " floatTowerAds";
        }
      } else {
        towerRightAd.className = "bodyTowerRightAd";
      }
    }
```